# Is PowerShell building hash table in the background for output?

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to understand how objects and hash tables are working in Powershell. I know the difference between those two but I’m a litt bit confused about one ting. If I run Get-Service so I get an output with names, display names etc. does it mean that this is an Hashtable that Powershell is building in the background? I know that hashtable is key=value but when I get output from get-service it’s more that 2 columns. I’m just bit confused about what I’m seeing in Powershell :)

Comment: To see what properties a cmdlet exposes use `Get-Member` --> `Get-Service|Get-Member`

Comment: That topic is quite broad. Here are [some](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/29/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/) [starting](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/) [points](https://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Decorating-Objects/), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to explain in this way:

> 1. In PowerShell everything is an object.

- Hashtables are objects.
- Strings are objects.
- Integers are objects.
- Arrays are objects.
- Arrays of objects are objects
- etc.

> 2. In PowerShell Functions and Cmdlts interact with objects and return objects.

Functions and Cmdlets, like `Get-Service`, return an object. For ex. run:

```
$Services = Get-Service
$Services.GetType()


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Here you see that `$Services` is a type `Object[]` (an array of objects). Since the Cmdlet `Get-Service` outputs an object, we can then pass it along to another function by piping it. i.e.

```
$Services = Get-Service
$Services | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\services.csv'
```

This will output the object to a CSV file. You can do further piping such as adding in `Where-Object` to do some filtering etc. This all leads us to the crux of the question:

> 3. How do you visualize an object?

When you run `Get-Service`, it outputs an object, and hands it to the PowerShell's console. What you are seeing is PowerShell's console's **interpretation** of what an object of type `Object[]` should look like. Similarly, hash tables and 2 column arrays can be interpreted and **displayed** the same, even though in the back end, they are different **types** of objects.